# A newer version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7 than 23.2.1 is available: 24.0.0-alpha1

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Appears the following error

> A newer version of com.android.support:appcompat-v4 than 23.2.1 is
>   available: 24.0.0-alpha1 and A newer version of
>   com.android.support:appcompat-v7 than 23.2.1 is available:
>   24.0.0-alpha1

my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zkc.i2ctools"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile files('libs/core-3.1.0.jar')
}
```

Gradle build with error .What is wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to import eclipse project in android studio

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you're trying to do and why you're not able to accomplish this. [Here's a link for reference on how to ask a good question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is not an error, it's a warning. Warnings simply notify you that something may need your attention, but it doesn't necessarily mean anything is wrong in your code. In this case, it's a known bug and lint shouldn't be directing you to use the alpha, but this shouldn't be preventing your app from building. Is your build is failing, something else is wrong.

Answer (score 24):

actually, there is a bug, "Lint should not suggest alpha version of support library dependency"
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203270

**Update (21-March-2016)**

The bug has been merged with this 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203321
and fixed for 2.1 Future release, on March 11

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you may be confusing that info level log item with an error level log item. Logs like this will happen through out your application. However this does not mean anything in your application is broken.

I do not believe you should upgrade to the newer versions of appcompat until they are out of alpha unless they contain critical features/bug fixes that you require.

If it is unable to build, that's another story altogether.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm beginner in Android. In event log appears :"Gradle build finished with 1 error(s)"  and in messages manifesr merger failed error

Answer (score 0):

If you want Lint to stop suggesting alpha versions, you can configure it creating lint.xml in project root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lint>
    <!-- Don't warn about available alpha versions -->
    <issue id="GradleDependency">
        <ignore regexp="is available: .*alpha" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

If you prefer you can avoid beta versions too replacing <ignore ... /> line:

```
<ignore regexp="is available: .*[alpha|beta]" />
```